# DynamicPlaceholder get Parameter Templates Treelistvalues

Tags: dynamic-placeholder, tree-list

I've created a Parameters Template with a Treelist Field and a Rendering which uses this Template. That works so far I can select multiple values. But Now I am using this rendering in a dynamic Placeholder and I want to get the Selected Values from my Parameter. The Only thing I get at the moment are Pipe separated GUIDs and I was hoping that I could use MultilistField to get the Values from my selection. But I don't know how to initialize the Multilistfield. Because the Guids I am currently getting with the following Function

```
public string GetParameter(DynamicPlaceholderRenderContext context, string parameter)
{
        var parameterValue = context.Parameters.ContainsKey(parameter) ? context.Parameters[parameter] :
             context.Rendering.Parameters.Contains(parameter) ? context.Rendering.Parameters[parameter] :
             string.Empty;

        return parameterValue;
 }
```

which I Call in my view inside the wrapper Method fpr my DynamicPlaceholder

```
 @Html.Sitecore().DynamicPlaceholder("grid-column", CreateWrapper)

 @functions
 {

     private readonly IParameterTemplatesProvider _parameterTemplatesService = new ParameterTemplatesProvider();

     HtmlString CreateWrapper(HtmlString htmlString, DynamicPlaceholderRenderContext context)
     { 
        var cssClasses = _parameterTemplatesService.GetParameter(context, Templates.GridBase.Fields.CssClassesFieldName);


     }
 }
```

When I try to get some "context" data like this

```
var test = Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields[Templates.Column.Fields.CssClassesFieldName];
```

I get null back but no Object or something else where I can create a MultilistField. I Think I've some prober missunderstandings when I can access

Sitecore.Context.Item or RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item how can get the Real Selected values from my Treelist

I am not shure if my problems are associated with DynamicPlaceholders or some other missunderstandings in the sitecore technology :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rendering parameters are stored as name-value-collection (like a query string) with just the raw value - which for a multi-list field is a pipe-separated list of IDs.

You could change your `GetParameter()` method to something like the following, to get a list of items:

```
public IList<Item> GetParameter(DynamicPlaceholderRenderContext context, string parameter)
{
    var parameterValue = context.Parameters.ContainsKey(parameter) ? context.Parameters[parameter] :
            context.Rendering.Parameters.Contains(parameter) ? context.Rendering.Parameters[parameter] :
            string.Empty;

    // You might want to do some more checks here
    // - check for valid IDs, non-null items returned etc.
    return parameterValue.Split(new [] {'|'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                         .Select(id => Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(id))
                         .ToList();
}
```

As noted you might want to do some error-checking just in case.

Comment: So afte this I get the Items I think that works now, but I am not able to get the Value from my Items. I've tried to run throug my return values with a foreach and then use "item[Templates.Column.Fields.CssClassesFieldName]" to get the value but I never get any value back

Comment: It sounds like you might be confusing the field name of the rendering parameter field (for the multi-list) and the field name on the actual CssClass item with the actual value.

Comment: Yes that was the Problem, some naming Problems :-/ and I've tried to get the values from the wrong Object. It's hard that you can't see which values are assinged to an item in the debugger then I should have found my problem earlier